# How do I redirect example.com/example to an outside URL?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm guessing it needs to be htaccess. I tried:

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.newurl.com/
```

but that lands me at newurl.com/example.

Comment: What do you expect the end result to be?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want directly to another URL, you can use a `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^example http://www.newurl.com [L,R=301]
```